# Simple Carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

[www.beulahprint.ie](http://www.beulahprint.ie)

I've been looking for ages for a basic carousel with no bells and whistles. I'm new to coding so I'm finding it very tough to customise and simplify a complex carousel to suit my needs. I have a basic one working on my site, but there are issues with it I need help with:

1) It seems to be jumping down the page about 20px from where it should be?
2) How do I remove the Previous/Next buttons?
3) How do I turn the 1, 2 ,3 4 tabs into custom tabs with rollovers and position them wherever I want within the div?

I would greatly appreciate this one guys.

Cheers,
Colm

Answer (score 0):

For your first two question:

1. Yor `#header`'s proper height seems to be 150px instead of 180px;
2. You can try adding `.carousel-control {display:hidden;}` to your CSS.

Comment: I have the header at 180px so that when I delete the special offers for all the other pages, the white graphic below it will slide up to where the special offer div started (30px below the top of the blue graphic). I think the previous button is causing my specialoffer image to slide down about 20px?

I tried adding that line to my CSS but it didnt change anything, I'm not sure i put it in the right place? I put it in my "styles.css" file?

Answer (score 0):

> - [Scrollable, Carousel, Slider in jquery without any plugin - the simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251649/scrollable-carousel-slider-in-jquery-without-any-plugin-the-simplest-way/5252836#5252836)

try this little script i have made some time ago...