# How to animate the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hoba8e7/10/)

As you can see from the fiddle that there is a list that is being scrolled with the help of arrows.. So what I want is to animate that transition when the list visible and hidden.

I don't know about the animation. I have seen many examples and tried to adjust them with my example but it's not working... How do I get the list to animate?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var code='';
    for(var i=1;i<=20;i++)
    {
        code+="<li>list Item "+i+"</li>";
    }
    $('#list-items').html(code);        
        
});


var list_items = [];
var index = 0;
var list_length = 0;

function getAllListItems() {
    var temp = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        list_items.push(temp[i]);
    }

    list_length = temp.length;
}

getAllListItems();

function move(dir) {


    if (dir == left) {
        list_items[index].style.display = 'block';
        index--;

        if (index < 0) {
            index = 0;
        }
    } else if (dir == right) {

        list_items[index].style.display = 'none';

        if (index >= ((list_length) - 1)) {
            index = (list_length) - 1;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    } else {}
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
ul li:first-child {
    display: block;
}
#left, #right {
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    background-color:aqua;
    font-size:2em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload='getAllListItems()'>
    <div id='t'></div>
    <button id='left' onClick="move(left)">
        <</button>
           
                <ul id='list-items'>
                    
                </ul>
         
            <button id='right' onClick='move(right)'>></button>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice Question  I also want to know about the animation to the list..and nice logic for the carousel menu..I have seen this first time

Comment: There's a lot of libraries for that. One by memory : Slick; try this out http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Hi, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5252836/1841852

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily just replace your lines:

```
list_items[index].style.display = 'block';
list_items[index].style.display = 'none';
```

with the jQuery `show()` and `hide()` functions:

```
$(list_items[index]).show("slow");
$(list_items[index]).hide("slow");
```

As demonstrated in my updated version of your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hoba8e7/12/)

For different transitions, you can use the `animate()` function, which lets you tell it what css properties to affect. In addition to numeric values, jQuery also supports the special values `'show'`, `'hide'`, and `'toggle'` (which, incidentally, will show, hide, or toggle the show/hide status of an element using that property). So for instance, if you wanted to shrink them only horizontally and leave the vertical alone, you could change the `.show()` and `.hide()` calls to:

```
$(list_items[index]).animate({width:'show'}, 600);
$(list_items[index]).animate({width:'hide'}, 600);
```

I've demonstrated this in another updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hoba8e7/42/)

Comment: when it is being hidden that looks like some awkward ..how can I animate it something different?

Comment: plus1 for the Simplicity

Comment: I've edited my post to include a little bit about other possible ways to animate it.